# Generate group policy settings report on windows server

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012, group-policy

I current have a windows server, with the server manager running. Under the group policy management console, gpo entries with settings has been created for domain users and domain computers. There are multiple gpo which are link enabled(according to ms, highest priority GPO at the top of the list). My question is, to find out which of the settings is configured and to what values i will have to go into individual gpo->user policy/computer policy then into each settings to see. Is there a way to generate a document of the settings stored?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a save report button that will generate a report of everything listed and puts it in a html file.

If you go to the group policy management -> Action -> Save Report.